# Filter grep command

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

My file contains:

```
<xyz name="hello" desc="hello"/><xyz name="hello1" desc="hello1"/><xyz name="hello2" desc="hello2"/><abc name="hello4" desc="hello4"/><abc name="hello5" desc="hello5"/>
```

My Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
test=`grep 'xyz' file`
echo $test
```

This is giving me output as

```
<xyz name="hello" desc="hello"/><xyz name="hello1" desc="hello1"/><xyz name="hello2" desc="hello2"/>
```

I want my output as

```
name="hello" desc="hello"
name="hello1" desc="hello1"
name="hello2" desc="hello2"
```

Comment: Use a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 4):

`grep` loves these things:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=<xyz )[^/]*' file
name="hello" desc="hello"
name="hello1" desc="hello1"
name="hello2" desc="hello2"
```

#### Explanation

- `-Po` use Perl regular expressions (`-P`) and print only the matches (`-o`).
- `(?<=<xyz )[^/]*`

  - `(?<=<xyz )` start catching from after the `<xyz` string.
  - `[^/]*` match all characters up to the `/` character.

Comment: `-P` is actually `PCRE` or Perl Compatible Regular Expression and **is** different from perl regular expressions (although the differences are minor). Some of the differences are highlighted [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions#Differences_from_Perl)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this `sed` command also,

```
sed -r 's/^<xyz ([^/]*)\/><xyz ([^/]*)\/><xyz ([^/]*)\/>.*$/\1\n\2\n\3/g' file
```

Output:

```
name="hello" desc="hello"
name="hello1" desc="hello1"
name="hello2" desc="hello2"
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='/>' 'sub(/^<xyz /,"")' file
name="hello" desc="hello"
name="hello1" desc="hello1"
name="hello2" desc="hello2"
```